# Как в конце строки вставить многоточие?

Tags: php, строки

Есть множество строк с тегами например: `<p></p><p></p> <p></p>`

они не применено заканчиваются `</p>` тегом , как в конце последней строки до `</p>` средствами php вставить многоточие: `...</p>`

Comment: какой смысл делать это на пхп, если с этим хорошо справляется css ?

Comment: но в целом вы можете найти последнее вхождение `</p>` и заменить его на `&hellip;</p>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

как альтернативный вариант

```css
p:last-child::after {
   content: '\2026';
   color: red;
   font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>123</p>
  <p>234</p>
  <p>345</p>
</div>
```